# How to use Nlogger in Android

Tags: android, .net, maui, nlog

We are using Nlogger in MAUI application, We use different configuration depends on from platforms for example

```
#if WINDOWS
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<NLog.Logger>(NLog.LogManager.Setup().LogFactory.LoadConfiguration("Windows-NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger());
#elif ANDROID
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<NLog.Logger>(NLog.LogManager.Setup().LogFactory.LoadConfiguration("Android-NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger());
#else...
#endif
```

And our android nlog Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.MauiLog"/>
  </extensions>

  <variable name="logPath" value="${environment:folder=Personal}" />

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <target name="liteDB" xsi:type="liteDBTarget"
          connectionString="file=NLog.db"
          collectionName="DefaultLog" FlushTimeout="100" BufferSize="100" SlidingTimeout="true" OverflowAction="Flush">
    <property name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />
    <property name="ThreadName" layout="${threadname}" />
    <property name="ProcessID" layout="${processid}" bsonType="Int32"  />
    <property name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
    <property name="UserName" layout="${windows-identity}" />
  </target>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to console target for faster startup detection -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="lifetimeConsole, ownFile" final="true" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="ownFile" />
  </rules>


</nlog>
```

When I trying to run project while emulating Pixel 5 and get

: 'Failed to load NLog LoggingConfiguration. Searched the following locations:

- /data/user/0/com.companyname.starter/files/Android-NLog.config

And off course there no any conf file in Android/data/companyname.starter,
I set copy if never on build actions.

I understand reason but i dont know how to configure deployment for android correctly to nlog conf file appears in this place.

Comment: Maybe embed the `NLog.config` as assembly-resource in the application-project. And load it like this `NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-config-from-assembly-resource

Comment: You right, nloger now initialized correctly, but still nloger not creating any file in android/data/com.companyname.starter

Comment: Have you tried to enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and looked for warnings? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Comment: Example MAUI application can be found here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/tree/master/examples/MauiApp2 . See also tutorial here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration work for me :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog 
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Debug"
      internalLogFile="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}\Log\nlog-internal"

      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.LiteDB"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="liteDB" xsi:type="liteDBTarget"
          connectionString="special=${ApplicationData}\NLog.db"
          collectionName="DefaultLog" FlushTimeout="100" BufferSize="100" SlidingTimeout="true" OverflowAction="Flush">
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="liteDB" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="liteDB" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I set Nlog.config as embedded resource and copy if newest.

My logger singleton definition looks like this :

```
#if WINDOWS
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<NLog.Logger>(NLog.LogManager.Setup().LogFactory.LoadConfiguration("Windows-NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger());
#elif ANDROID

            try
            {

                Assembly assembly1 = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                NLog.Config.ISetupBuilder setupBuilder = NLog.LogManager.Setup();
                NLog.Config.ISetupBuilder configuredSetupBuilder = setupBuilder.LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(assembly1);
                Logger configuredLogger = configuredSetupBuilder.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<NLog.Logger>(configuredLogger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ;
            }

#endif
```